# SSH auth failed : Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, public-key

I have a particular context. I want to bind Jenkins to Git. Jenkins is running on Tomcat and I use a Docker container to run Git Server (https://hub.docker.com/r/unixtastic/git-ssh-server)

The trouble is that Jenkins fails to connect to Git. So, in order to identify the trouble shoot, I first try to connect to Git Server throw ssh in command line :

```
$ ssh git@172.17.0.2
```

Connection succeed and I can log to Git Server. But it does with login/password. But I would like to do it with public key.

So when I disable login/password login in Git Server sshd_config file, now login fails unless I think my config is right :

1. I created a pair of keys with ssh-keygen. This keys are located on the client in /home/git/.ssh
2. I copied the public key on the Git Server under git user's home : /git/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. The server public key is well copied in client user's known_hosts file after try to login

But unfortunately, login fails with the full message :

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.17.0.2 [172.17.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.17.0.2:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:103879AadyMX3oJAuSWHR74aQhBaZIg3yb95v6/FyeI
debug1: Host '172.17.0.2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/git/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: what do you see in the server log? And if you bump log level?

Comment: Your client offered id_rsa to the server and the server didn't accept it. There are at least half a dozen things on the server which could cause this. This is a pretty common question on [su] and [unix.se]. You should search for "Permission denied (publickey)" on those sites.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I use another docker image : gogs which runs well. https://hub.docker.com/r/gogs/gogs/